# How to type annotate converting envvar to integer?

Tags: python, mypy

How would I get mypy to accept this code?

```
try:
    DEBUG = int(os.getenv("DEBUG")) > 0
except ValueError:
    DEBUG = False
```

Current diagnostic is `mypy: Argument 1 to "int" has incompatible type "str | None"; expected "str | Buffer | SupportsInt | SupportsIndex | SupportsTrunc" [arg-type]`

Comment: May be use `int(os.environ["DEBUG"]) > 0`?

Comment: `int(os.getenv("DEBUG", 0)) > 0` ? Not sure whether mypy takes note of the type of the defaut value though.

Comment: `os.getenv("DEBUG")` can be `None` if `DEBUG` is not set, and `int(None)` fails, so, obviously, `mypy` did its job here: caught a type error you have. Either provide a default (`os.getenv('DEBUG', '0')`), or `_debug = os.getenv('DEBUG'); assert _debug; DEBUG = int(_debug)>0`, or `try: DEBUG = int(os.environ['DEBUG']) > 0; except (KeyError, ValueError): DEBUG = False`, there must also be other options. It doesn't matter that you wrap the expression with `try/except`, this does not allow type-unsafe calls within `try`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that mypy is warning you about is that your code will raise a `TypeError` if `os.getenv` returns `None`.  That's probably something you didn't intend!

I would usually fix this type of bug (and mypy error) by writing something like this as:

```
try:
    DEBUG = int(os.getenv("DEBUG") or 0) > 0
except ValueError:
    DEBUG = False
```

assuming that you want to treat `$DEBUG` as defaulting to zero (off).  The `or 0` means that if `os.getenv` returns a falsey value (i.e. either `None` or `''`) the expression will take the value of 0, which is a valid argument to `int()` and will result in `DEBUG = False`.

For the specific case of `os.getenv` you can conveniently get the same effect by supplying a "default" arg that will get returned instead of None:

```
try:
    DEBUG = int(os.getenv("DEBUG", "0")) > 0
except ValueError:
    DEBUG = False
```

When this arg is provided, the return type is `str` rather than `str | None`, since it is no longer possible for `None` to be returned.

You could also do something like:

```
try:
    debug_var = os.getenv("DEBUG")
    if debug_var is None:
        raise ValueError
    DEBUG = int(debug_var) > 0
except ValueError:
    DEBUG = False
```

In this version of the code, `debug_var` starts off with the type `str | None`, and the `if debug_var is None: raise ...` causes its type to be narrowed to `str` in the remainder of that block.  This is a more general-purpose way to narrow a union type.

Comment: `os.getenv` takes an optional second argument to use as a default if the named variable isn't defined: `int(os.getenv("DEBUG", "0"))`.

Comment: Even better, then!  (And it looks like the type stubs do provide the right overloading.)